# Верстка горизонтальных блоков с помощью flex. Центральный блок всегда по центру

Tags: html, css3

Возможно ли с помощью Flex оставлять третий блок всегда по центру когда область экрана делать меньше.
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если делать все блоки шириной по 20% - то не получится максимального сжатия блока в целом с учётом того чтобы третий блок всегда был по центру и не было переносов строк.
Без использования Grid

Answer (score 0):

В flexbox можно ставить даже фиксированные размеры,но это не будет работать

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.item {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.items2 {
  width: 90%;
}

.items3 {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item">какой то текст</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="items items2">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="items items3">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пока решение увидел только в том, чтобы сделать три блока. Один центральный и два по краям. В крайнем случае обрамить крайние элемены через JS
Тогда правые элементы максимально сожмутся прежде чем будет сдвинут центральный блок.

```
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="block wrap-block">
        <div class="block block1">Первый блок</div>
        <div class="block block2">Второй блок</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block block3">Средний блок</div>
    <div class="block wrap-block">
        <div class="block block4">Четвёртый блок средний</div>
        <div class="block block5">Пятый блок самый большой</div>
    </div>
</div>


    .wrap {
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -moz-flex;
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: -o-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        color: #eee;
    }
    .block {
        flex:1;
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 3em;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #3f51b5dd , #00BCD4dd);
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -moz-flex;
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: -o-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
    .block3 {
        flex: 0 200px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .block.wrap-block {
        background: none;
    }
    .block3:after {
        display: block;
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        border-right: 1px solid #0f0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%);
    }
    .wrap:after {
        display: block;
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        border-right: 1px solid #f00;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%);
    }
```